# Best practices for sharing contracts when using Google Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

What are some effective ways to share contracts between peer applications, when using Google Protobuffers as the transport? Have any best practices emerged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking between different platforms, your best bet is to simply put the .proto schema definition somewhere accessible - could be documentation, could be a download. Each platform can generate their code from there.